# Métodos estáticos o dinámicos?

Tags: java

En OOP la mayor parte de las personas tienden a programar todo en métodos de instancia incluso cuando el método sea independiente de las instancias. Mi pregunta es la siguiente: Merece la pena pararse a pensar que métodos deberían ser static? Generaría alguna ventaja de rendimiento sacar esos métodos de la instancia? Y si no genera ninguna ventaja, de que sirve el static? Gracias por las respuestas

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Es una muy buena pregunta para los recien llegados a la programación.

Answer (score 4):

Tu respuesta puede ser muy amplia, aún así intentaré contestar-te:

> Una regla empírica: **¿Tiene sentido llamar a este método, incluso si
>   todavía no se ha construido el objeto en cuestión?** Si es así, definitivamente debe ser
>   estático.

Por lo tanto, en una clase, `Coche` es posible que tenga un método double `convertMphToKmph(double mph)` que sería estático, porque uno podría querer saber a qué se convierte 35mph, incluso si nadie ha construido un automóvil. Pero void `setMileage(double mpg)`(lo que establece la eficiencia de un automóvil en particular) no puede ser estático, ya que es inconcebible llamar al método antes de que se haya construido un automóvil.

(Por cierto, lo contrario no siempre es cierto: a veces puede tener un método que involucre dos `Coches`, y aún así quiera que sea estático. Por ejemplo, Coche `theMoreEfficientOf( Car c1, Car c2 )` aunque esto podría convertirse a una versión no estática, algunos argumentarían que ya que no es una opción "privilegiada" de la cual el automóvil es más importante, no debe forzar a la persona que llama a elegir un `coche` como el objeto al que invocará el método. Aunque esta situación representa una fracción bastante pequeña de todos los métodos estáticos.)

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu respuesta es excelente, sobre todo la regla empírica que propones. Tan solo me queda la duda de lo que se debería hacer con las clases que se crean exclusivamente para operar con un obieto, (es decir que no se usan como tipo de datos) . Tiene sentido que sean de métodos static? Con todos los que he hablado los static no los ven más allá del main y los singletones, y me queda un hormigueo extraño al pensar que tal vez haya más cosas útiles que hacer con ellos.

Comment: Tu mismo te respondes a la pregunta, si són clases que se crean exclusivamente para operar con objetos no contendrán métodos static, aunque si en esas clases creas métodos que tienen sentido usarlos sin crear el objeto, éstos métodos serán static.